# React Element I want to unit test is state dependent, but testing state is not recommended in RTL. What to do?

Tags: react-testing-library

I know I should not test state with React Testing Library. But in my case the visibility of element is depended on state of the component.

As you see in this code,

```js
export const SliderContainer = ({ totalSliderItems, sliderItems }: SliderProps): JSX.Element => {
 const [activeSlideItem, setActiveSlideItem] = useState<number>(0);

 const changeActiveSlideItem = (action: string): void => {
   switch (action) {
     case 'prev':
       activeSlideItem > 0 && setActiveSlideItem(activeSlideItem - 1);
       break;
     case 'next':
       activeSlideItem < totalSliderItems && setActiveSlideItem(activeSlideItem + 1);
       break;
   }
 }

 return (
   <div className='relative'>
     <SliderButton data-testid="prevButton" type="prev" onClick={() => { changeActiveSlideItem('prev') }} disabled={activeSlideItem === 0 && true}/>
       {/* Create an array with length totalSlideItems and then render SliderItem totalSlideItems times */}
       <div className="slide flex" style={{ transform: `translateX(-${activeSlideItem * 100}%)` }}>
         {Array.from({ length: totalSliderItems }, (_, index) => {
           return <SliderItem
                     key={index}
                     imageSrc={sliderItems[index].imageSrc}
                     imageAlt={sliderItems[index].imageAlt}
                     sliderItemDescription={sliderItems[index].sliderItemDescription}
                 />
         })}
       </div>
       <SliderButton data-testid="nextButton" type="next" onClick={() => { changeActiveSlideItem('next') }} disabled={activeSlideItem === totalSliderItems - 1 && true}/>
   </div>
 )
}
```

code for SliderButton

```js
import classNames from 'classnames';
import { MouseEventHandler } from 'react';

interface SliderButtonProps {
  type: string
  onClick?: MouseEventHandler
  disabled?: boolean
  className?: boolean
}
export const SliderButton = ({ type, onClick, disabled, className }: SliderButtonProps): 
JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <button onClick={onClick} className={classNames(className, 'absolute sliderButton', disabled && 'disabled')} data-testid={`${type}-button`}>
        {type}
    </button>
  )
};
```

the prop `disable` is dependent on value of the state `activeSlideItem`. So, to test is the button disabled or not, somehow I must set value to the `activeSlideItem` during unit testing. But as far as I know, we should not test state with React Testing Library because RTL runs the test from user perspective and users have no idea about component state. What can I do? I can't use enzyme either because I found a lot of articles which say Enzyme is dead. Or is there any other smarter way to perform the test?

my Jest code..

```js
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import SliderContainer from './slider';

describe('slider test', () => {
  const sliderItems = [{
    imageSrc: 'images/test/test.jpg',
    imageAlt: 'test',
    sliderItemDescription: 'test'
  }, {
    imageSrc: 'images/test/test.jpg',
    imageAlt: 'test',
    sliderItemDescription: 'test'
  }, {
    imageSrc: 'images/test/test.jpg',
    imageAlt: 'test',
    sliderItemDescription: 'test'
  }]
  it('previous button is disabled when activeSliderItem is 0', () => {
    const slider = render(<SliderContainer sliderItems={sliderItems} totalSliderItems={sliderItems.length}/>)
    // code for testing is prev button is disabled ..
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to manually set the `activeSlideItem` state to the proper value. The idea with Testing Library is that you perform some user interaction, like clicking the next and previous buttons, and then test that the interface responds correctly (in this case, setting the "disabled" class on the button).

The following example is assuming the `@testing-library/user-event` library; adjust as necessary. `user-event` is recommended over the `fireEvent` methods, although either should work here. There are also libraries like `@testing-library/jest-dom` which just add some helpful matchers, like for checking that an element has a class. It's possible to test classes manually like I've done below (this is just one way of doing so), but the `jest-dom` library would have a better error message for failures.

```js
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'
import SliderContainer from './slider';

describe('slider test', () => {
  const sliderItems = [{
    imageSrc: 'images/test/test.jpg',
    imageAlt: 'test',
    sliderItemDescription: 'test'
  }, {
    imageSrc: 'images/test/test.jpg',
    imageAlt: 'test',
    sliderItemDescription: 'test'
  }, {
    imageSrc: 'images/test/test.jpg',
    imageAlt: 'test',
    sliderItemDescription: 'test'
  }]

  it('previous button is disabled when activeSliderItem is 0', async () => {
    const slider = render(<SliderContainer sliderItems={sliderItems} totalSliderItems={sliderItems.length} />)

    const prev = slider.getByRole('button', { name: 'prev' })
    const next = slider.getByRole('button', { name: 'next' })

    const user = userEvent.setup()

    expect(prev.className.split(' ')).toContain('disabled')
    expect(next.className.split(' ')).not.toContain('disabled')

    await user.click(next)
    expect(prev.className.split(' ')).not.toContain('disabled')
    expect(next.className.split(' ')).not.toContain('disabled')

    await user.click(next)
    expect(prev.className.split(' ')).not.toContain('disabled')
    expect(next.className.split(' ')).toContain('disabled')
  })
})
```